# How can i plot markers on map swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm taking JSON's data and storing all geox coming from JSON in geox and geoy in geoy.
while plotting markers by for loop throws me error "cannot convert value of type NSArray to expected argument type CLLocationDegrees(aka Double)"

```
let data = JSON as! NSDictionary
let result = Data["result"] as! NSArray                
let geox = result.valueForKey("geo_x") as! NSArray
let geoy = result.valueForKey("geo_y") as! NSArray
let count = geox.count
for index in 0...count {
    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geox,geoy)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you receive two separate arrays : one for longitude coordinates and another for latitude.

So you can do something like that :
First replace this :

```
let geox = result.valueForKey("geo_x") as! NSArray
let geoy = result.valueForKey("geo_y") as! NSArray
```

by this :

```
let geox = result.valueForKey("geo_x") as! [CLLocationDegrees]
let geoy = result.valueForKey("geo_y") as! [CLLocationDegrees]
```

and then :

```
for index in 0...count {
    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geox[index],geox[index])
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

Comment: throwing error as cannot convert value of type Anyobject to expected argument type CLLocationDegrees and when i put (latitude,longitude) instead of (geox[index],geoy[index]) gives "could not cast value of type NSNull to NSNumber

Comment: it is still not working giving me Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION while running

Comment: you should use optional :
`let geox = result.valueForKey("geo_x") as? [CLLocationDegrees]`
then check if geox is nil or not.
At least if it doesn't work try 
`let geox = result.valueForKey("geo_x") as! [Double]`
then cast `double` in `CLLocationDegrees`

Comment: Thank You So Much Maxime It Worked